# How to add double quotation marks ("") around pipe-separated fields

Tags: bash, sed, command-line

Let's say I have a file with this structure:

```
1|2|3|4|
5|6|7|8|
9|10|11|12|
```

However, I want my file to look like this (expected output):

```
"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|
"5"|"6"|"7"|"8"|
"9"|"10"|"11"|"12"|
```

I am trying to used `sed` command in the following way:

```
sed 's/^/"/g'
```

Unfortunately, it only adds quotation marks at the beginning of each line:

```
"1|2|3|4|
"5|6|7|8|
"9|10|11|12|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -E 's/[^|]+/"&"/g' file > newfile
```

The `-E` option enables the POSIX ERE syntax and `[^|]+` thus matches one or more chars other than `|`, and `"&"` replaces each with its copy enclosed with `"` on both sides.

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/Rls7Xg):

```sh
s='1|2|3|4|
5|6|7|8|
9|10|11|12|'
sed -E 's/[^|]+/"&"/g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|
"5"|"6"|"7"|"8"|
"9"|"10"|"11"|"12"|
```

Comment: This work perfectly fine but do you know how to apply it to each line except to the first one?

Comment: @brenda `sed -E '2,$ s/[^|]+/"&"/g'` - start from the second through the last line.

Answer (score 3):

`^` means "the beginning of a line". Use `[^|]` instead which means "anything but `|`". If your implementation of sed supports `+`, you can use

```
sed -E 's/[^|]+/"&"/g'
```

otherwise, you need to be more verbose

```
sed  's/[^|][^|]*/"&"/g'
```

`&` represents the matched part.

Comment: Probably you want to put double quotes around each character that is not "|"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `gnu awk` way of doing the same:

```sh
awk -v RS="[|\n]+" '{ORS=RT; print "\"" $0 "\""}' file

"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|
"5"|"6"|"7"|"8"|
"9"|"10"|"11"|"12"|
```